# Extract MIME body staying with pure .NET framework

Tags: .net, mime

Since .NET Framework already have System.Net.Mime namespace and is able to parse Http headers, I hope there should be also "standard" or "hidden" method to extract mime body (base64 encoded) from message (passed as a string or stream).

Where?

P.S. now I use regexps but that is not so interesting end not so durable...
P.P.S .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: When you say 'extract mime body from message', what exactly is 'message' here - what is the encoding inside the stream/string?

Comment: MIME headers and MIME body. With multipart start and finish "marks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any interesting inside .NET framework, after several hours of exploring  with reflector.

1. System.Net.Mime classes are used only to deserialize data (for .NET SMTP client that can only send emails).

2 I found that HTTP headers parser is also not very useful, have a look at
WebHeaderCollection's class, 
internal DataParseStatus ParseHeaders(byte[] buffer, int size, ref int unparsed, ref int totalResponseHeadersLength, int maximumResponseHeadersLength, ref WebParseError parseError) method. It requires to know where to stop. That means preparsing.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit). It is a fully managed (C#) MIME parser that is very very fast, very robust and standards-compliant.

There's a fully regex implementation called MIMER, but it takes 70x longer to parse a message than MimeKit's parser.

There exists no MIME parser written in C# that is more robust or faster than MimeKit - heck, there probably aren't any C/C++ parsers that are (much) faster than MimeKit (I've benchmarked MimeKit against some of the best C parsers and it is on par with their performance).